# When Calling from cron "subprocess.Popen " in a script is not working

Tags: cron, python

I have python script in which i am calling the other script using `subprocess.Popen`

```
subprocess.Popen("python sample.py", shell=True)
```

When running manually `sample.py` is running fine but when scheduled in cron `sample.py` is not executing. Please help

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help, see the part about code (block) formatting

Comment: What does "is not executing" mean, exactly? What happens instead? Do you get some error message? What does the error say? How are you running it? What do you have in the crontab, exactly? Remember, we can't see into your system to check the actual situation, you'll have to tell the details too.

Comment: let's say i have script test.py.  In test.py i am calling some other python script sample.py using subprocess.Popen("python sample.py", shell=True). When calling it from linux terminal like " python test.py " script test.py & sample.py is executed properly. But when i calling from cron the sample.py script is not executing & no error is coming.

Comment: you need to show the code. Everything needed to make the issue present itself. If what you have is too long to post, edit it into a minimal version that shows the issue. It's no use for anyone to guess what you might have there, when you have the actual code in front of you, and could just post it. You can [edit] your question to add whatever is needed, formatting in comments sucks.

Comment: `PATH` and other environnement variable are not set the same way in cron and in interactive session.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: I suspect your current working directory contains sample.py, and it's not your home directory. Can you confirm any of those?

Answer (score -3):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: I don't think the text about `$DISPLAY` or `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` is relevant here at all.  The user is using Python, not a shell script.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's an explanation of how the execution environment differs between desktop and `cron`. The original problem (and many others like it) is caused by a misunderstanding of execution environments.

Comment: Absolutely, but what does it mean in the context of this particular question, and what is the implication given what the questioner is doing?